# Am I right that Perl will read file content straight into memory?

Tags: perl

It can be quite obvious but I'd like to consult with you..

So I have the following perl module:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Slurp;


my @list = read_file_subroutine();

my %hash = map {$_ => 1} @list;

sub does_list_contain_smth() {
    my ($self, $data) = @_;
    if ($hash($data)) {
       return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

sub get_list() {
    return \@list;
}

sub read_file_subroutine {
    my $file = "/some/file/path/file.txt";
    my $content = read_file($file);
    my @list = split "\n", $content;
    return \@list

1;
```

Am I right that `read_file_subroutine` will be called only once and file content will be placed into memory?

Comment: Your code is all over the place. Why do you think you need a function to get the value of an array? Are you writing a module? You don't need to rewrite the `read_file` function, it already returns an array, if you read the documentation: 
`# read in a whole file into an array of lines
my @lines = read_file('/path/file');`

Comment: Tip: Consider using [File::Slurper](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Slurper) instead of File::Slurp.

Comment: also, you are putting the contents of the file in memory twice; once in a string containing the whole file, and once in individual strings for the lines; why not just `my @list = read_file($file)` or `my @list = File::Slurper::read_lines($file)`

Comment: Actually, at one point, it's in memory three times. And it's not really a problem. `my @list = read_file($file);` is better because it's cleaner, not because it avoids a memory copy or two.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

`read_file_subroutine` will only be called once. There's only one call to it, it's not in any kind of loop, and it's not a sub that's called more than once.

`read_file` does read the entire file into memory. The first sentence of its [documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Slurp#read_file):

> This function reads in an entire file and returns its contents to the caller